# Evaluating a binary classification time series model

Tags: time-series, multivariate-analysis, metric

Question: What metric should I use to compare time series models that are used for binary classification when the classes are highly imbalanced? Is there a way to get an average score that makes sense in this case?

Background:

I'm struggling to find an appropriate metric for model evaluation and comparison.

Multivariate binary time series data, and I'm interested in comparing several different models. My data are highly imbalanced (about 120 cases of class 0 for every case of class 1).

I would use f1 score, or AUROC, or average precision if this were a static case; however these are time series data. I'm not sure if averaging AUROC makes sense (as in, averaging over a sequence).

The data are 10,000 sequences, where each time point is a binary (0/1) matrix of size (986, 986).

I've read that:

- raw classification accuracy is not a good metric to use with imbalanced data
- sensitivity and specificity are not the best measures to use for imbalanced data.

Comment: Cohen's kappa coefficient is meant to deal with the imbalanced data issue

Comment: Thanks @OpenSeason, but what about in a time series context?

Comment: Do you care about things like "performance at time 1" vs "performance at time 2"?  Do you expect these numbers will be different?  If not, then you could just forget about time and lump all the results together.

Comment: I might start with lumping results together, but I wonder if I should care about performance at time t vs time (t+1). Do you have a clear idea of what the difference would mean in terms of what metrics I use?

Comment: Maybe more importantly: can you average ROC values, or is that actually bad?

Comment: You could average them, or take a median perhaps to be more stable, or plot a histogram of the values. Keep track of your standard deviation.  A visually intuitive approach would be to plot the AUC values as black/white values in a 986 x 986 image.